# Django.admin - How to make a Modelfield disable if other field is == False

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, django-model-field

I'm new to Django, and I'm developing a website in which I need to automate the creation of new pages through Django admin platform. So the idea is to create a new tab on the main menu of the site if a `display` parameters is set to `True`.

However I want to give the user the option to create a dropdown menu like this one,
[Dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uto67.png).

So my idea is to have a checkbox `Dropdown Menu`, that whenever the user sets it `True`, a list of all the available pages to "nest" under the dropdown menu will be automatically enabled below it. 
I'm attaching the admin page as it is today,[Admin fields.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSRTt.png).

---

models.py of app creat_pages

```
class CreatePage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Nome", max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField("Atalho")

    tittle = models.CharField("Título", max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField("Descrição", blank=True)
    body = models.TextField("Corpo", blank=True)
    display = models.BooleanField("Mostrar no Site", default=False)
    dropdown_menu = models.BooleanField("Dropdown Menu", default=False)
    dropdown_options = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, related_name='dropdown', 
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField("Criado em", auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField("Última alteração", auto_now=True)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.urls import reverse

        return reverse("create_pages:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Criar Página"
        verbose_name_plural = "Criar Paginas"
        ordering = ["-name"]
```

Admin.py:

```
class CreatePageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", "slug", "tittle", "display", "created_at"]
    search_fields = ["name", "slug", "tittle"]
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}

admin.site.register(CreatePage, CreatePageAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I just needed to know how to use `Foreignkey`. After I learned that it was pretty straight forward:

I created a `context_processor.py` that filters all pages that have `display = True`, and makes them available to all my templates' context. In this way I can render the pages pretty easily.

```
from .models import CreatePage  
def new_page(request):     
    display = CreatePage.objects.filter(dropdown__isnull=True, display=True)      
    return {"display": display}
```